# How to rotate preview device on InVision Cloud

Tags: invision-studio

I'm trying to prototype landscape mode for a tablet.

Is there a way to rotate the tablet device? I've been looking for like over an hour, and have found no such feature.

I need to rotate this preview device.

[image]

**edit**

I've tried rotating via desktop Studio version of InVision, with no results.

Answer (score 1):

https://support.invisionapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/203730685-How-do-I-change-my-prototype-type-or-orientation-

### V6 invision

- Sign in to your account.
- Open your prototype.
- Under the name of the prototype, next to the Assets tab, click the ••• (more) icon.
- Click Change Type.
- Select the prototype type and orientation you want.
- Click Continue to save.

### V7 invision

- Sign in to your InVision account.
- Navigate to your documents, and click the prototype you want to manage.
- At the top-right of the document landing page, click the ••• (more) button, and then click Change device type.
- In the Choose a device type dialog, click the type you want to use.
- If using any type other than Desktop, be sure to click an orientation option.
- Click the pink Change Type button.